# Cannot run parse program

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, parse-platform

This is very frustrating, I am trying to add the Parse framework but every time I do, my app crashes (even with no code added).  I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/ParseOSX.framework/ParseOSX
  Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Popup-beyvddmmqfabhhghmlsnrvkissfw/Build/Products/Debug/Popup.app/Contents/MacOS/Popup
  Reason: image not found
```

Sounds like it's having problems finding the framework?  There have been other people with this problem but I can find no solution short of creating a new project.  I'd rather just find another solution before doing that...

Comment: No that is a crash and is probably due to the dylib being missing from the frameworks folder, as it wasn't copied there during the build.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the frameworks to a new copy files build task.  Make sure that they end up in the build products folder, and the "copy only on install" checkbox is NOT checked.